# Java regex to find everything except for '.'

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will find everything except for `'.'` - that is, a string which only contains `'.'` should return `false` and everything else `true`.

```
String regex = "(?!(^\\.$)).*";
String test = ".";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Can you specify exactly what the problem is?

Comment: I think this will do the job [^\\.$].*

Comment: What should be result of `foo.bar` or `..`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?![.]$).*$
```

This should do it for you.You need to use `anchors` to make sure you dont make any partial matches.

Comment: This regex is virtually same with the original one.

Comment: @Unihedro this will not make partail matches which `OP` 's regex will make

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza when `.` is inside `[]` you dont need to escape it.

Comment: @vks Thanks this seems to work for me. However doesn't the .*$ mean match anything at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the job `[^.].*|[.].+`, i tried 15 different inputs on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, and it only says false when trying to find '.'

Explanation:

`[^.].*` - match everything that starts with no-dot character, and after that has 0 or more of any other characters,

`[.].+` - match everything that starts with dot, and is followed by at least one or more of any other characters.

`[^.].*|[.].+` - both parts merged with operator 'or'

Comment: Did you test it with `find` method? Also what ware your test cases? Did you try to match `$`?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, i found out that for inputs like '..' or '...' this regex fails :(

Comment: I edited, I think now it works!

Comment: Almost. You forgot about one special case: empty string `""` which doesn't start with dot nor non-dot.

Comment: Nice one! But I am not sure if that is a valid input in his case, if it is, we could add `|^$` at the end of my regex to match that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a regex for this, just use string comparison:

```
if (!".".equals(test)) {
    // not equal to a dot
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately yeah the api we are using accepts only a Pattern and uses matcher.find to find

Comment: Is it possible to use `if (!matcher.find())` ?